# Ruby rmagick: How to make text more bold?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, text, fonts, rmagick

```
def change_image_labels(feed_data)
 for data in feed_data
  img = Image::read(@tmpdir_file_path+"/#{data[0]}.png").first.resize(600,600)
 redback = Image::read("#{Rails.root}/tmp/redback.png")[0]
 txt = Magick::Draw.new
 redback.annotate(txt,0,0,0,0,data[2]){
   txt.gravity = Magick::WestGravity
   txt.pointsize = 50
   txt.fill = "#ffffff"
   txt.font_family = 'helvetica'
   txt.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
 }
 img = img.composite(redback, 0, 30, AtopCompositeOp)
 img.write(@tmpdir_file_path+"/#{data[0]}.png")
end
end
```

Here I am trying to annotate an image with reb background with a text.

```
Here `redback.annotate(txt,0,0,0,0,data[2]` `data[2]` refers to the text which contains data like 92% OFF. I want to make it bold.
```

Please refer to below images-

**Actual Result-**

[image]

**Desired Result (Boldness)-**

[image]

As you can the second image contains a text which is more bold.

Please help.

Comment: The font in your first image ("actual result") is not only not bold, it's definitely not Helvetica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get helvetica to look bold with Rmagick.
Your best bet might be to download a [bolder font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/tag/bold), copy it to your Rails project and tell RMagick to use it :

```
txt.font = "#{Rails.root}/lib/fonts/[font filename].ttf"
```

If you're very careful, you could make the text bolder (but possibly uglier) with :

```
txt.stroke_width = 1 # <-- adjust this parameter
txt.stroke = "#ffffff"
txt.stroke_antialias true
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had helvetica font. I was doing the same thing but I was placing that font file somewhere else. It worked by placing inside lib/fonts. Thanks again.